# Is this eye gunk on my Leopard Geckos eye a concern?

Tags: health, leopard-geckos

[image]

My leopard gecko has some type of gunk on the inner corner of his eye. His eyelid isn't shut. We used to have the ground up walnut shell bedding but just recently changed it to the felt pad bedding. I'm not sure how long he's had this gunk on his eye but I just noticed it.

Comment: it might be an infection maby from an foregn object so you need to take him to a vet.it looks infected to me so your gecko will probably need some medication.

Comment: Have you tried flushing it out with saline and moistened q-tips? You can also try using wet gauze as well. If it doesn't come off let me know.